# How do i round to the nearest whole number

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable, minute

I am calling ToMinutes() on a nullable DateTime, this returns a double butI wish to convert it to the *nearest whole number* if it is not null.

example: From `1534488.74496255` to `1534489`

How can I do this ?

Comment: Those being ~ 1534489 milliseconds? Which are 25.57481667 minutes, so ~ 26 minutes? Or what that value represents? Or you want to convert string '1534488.74496255' to 1534489 (being an integer) minutes ?

Comment: Is it string? Which out type do you want? Which format? What culture? Examples?

Comment: Is that a double value representing datetime?

Comment: @galakt invariant culture, and output type should just be a the nearest minute

Comment: `Math.Round(source)`? Or `(int) (source + 0.5)`?

Comment: @RazvanDumitru I think that is in minutes

Comment: `1534488.74496255` if *in minutes* is about *3 years*

Comment: Could do `Int.Parse(field);`

Comment: Math.Round takes in a double, this is a nullable date time field @DmitryBychenko

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes that is valid and doesnt matter in this case, i just want it rounded to the nearest whole number

Comment: what does this number represents? can you tell us at least what number of minutes you expect in return?

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled i have edited the question

Comment: So the question is how to extract this value `1534488.74496255` from`DateTime` object in order to round it use `Math.Round` ?

Comment: Then go with @DmitryBychenko suggestion of Math.Round.

Comment: I tried converting date using `DateTime.FromOADate()`  and got 13/04/6101 17:52:44

Comment: @ZoharPeled Math.Round takes in a double

Comment: @ifelabolz Can you at least explain in your question how you're getting this `DateTime` object ? And how do you know that it holds this number of minutes ? I can't seem to find this trivial.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko can you please put your answer in the answer section so i can mark it!. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to round, just round:

```
  double source = 1534488.74496255;

  // if you want double (i.e. floating point result)
  double result = Math.Round(source);

  // if you want integer outcome (and source is positive)
  int minutes = (int) (source + 0.5);

  // if you want integer outcome (general case)  
  int minutes = (int) (source > 0 ? source + 0.5 : source - 0.5);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, did not realise ToMinutes() returned double. :)

Comment: @ife labolz: you're welcome! Could you, please, edit your question as well? I mean, that you have `DateTime` field, then you call `ToMinutes()` on it which returns `double` and it's the `double` returned should be rounded up.

Comment: The `(int)(source + 0.5)` does bad things when you have negative numbers. `(int)Math.Round(source)` seems like a better option.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: thank you! Nice catch! I've edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Could it be something like the following you are after? This returns the closest lower integer.

```
int timeAsWholeMinute = (int) Math.Floor(timeInMinutes);
```

or if you just want the closest integer:

```
int timeAsWholeMinute = (int) Math.Round(timeInMinutes);
```